PetitParser2 Smalltalk grammar testing dataset
I would like to use PetitParser2 in Pharo.
I would like to use the Smalltalk grammar, but the testing dataset is not available anymore. Does anyone know where to get it?
Edit:
The filename missing is called smalltalk-src-selected.zip
The original site for it was at scb.unibe.ch
